# Merge candidates: Portmanteau words vs. Blend words

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[portmanteau-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portmanteau-words) and [blend-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blend-words) are both tags on ELU. What's the purpose of the summary-less [portmanteau-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portmanteau-words) tag? Is there a distinction between the two terms?

Answer (score 2):

I'd have liked to propose that [portmanteau-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portmanteau-words) be made a synonym of [blend-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blend-words). But I can't because I haven't scored at least 5 rep points in either (there aren't many questions for either).

So far as I know, if two tags are "merged", it doesn't really matter which is the "original" and which is the "synonym". But even if a proposal *can* be made, several (4?) more users with sufficient rep (2500?) still need to vote for the change, and they all need to have at least 5 points gained from questions in (one, both, or the "original"?) tag category, so it could take a while to go through.

It's been nearly a month now, and [joke/jokes](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/jokes/synonyms) are still waiting to be merged. I can't help there, because I don't have the necessary 5 points on those either.

If you've got the relevant rep, go ahead and upvote any [outstanding proposals](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) you think make sense. But be warned - many people don't like merging anything where there's any possibility of a distinction being made (once you merge, you can never regain that distinction). I don't expect [style/writing-style](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/writing-style/synonyms) to be merged any time soon, even though I voted for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think they mean the same, but I'd keep the [portmanteau-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portmanteau-words) tag.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, portmoneau is a specific kind of blend words that are mixing words deeper than just concatenating them and potentially making one or two letters common.

A "blendword" would be a plain blend word. A "blord" would be a portmoneau. A "bearshark" is a blend word of "bear" and "shark", but a "snark" is a portmoneau of "snake" and "shark".

Not casting my vote for/against merge either way.